# How to get multiple graphic cards information using nsis?

Tags: nsis, video-card

I am trying to create an installer using NSIS and there is one custom page for checking hardware requirement. Currently, I am using the [HwInfo plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/HwInfo_plug-in), but the problem is the function GetVideoCardName only return 1 graphic card name even though the desktop has multiple graphic cards.

How can I get all installed graphic cards name using NSIS?

**UPDATE:**

I use [WMI header](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WMI_header) to get all graphic cards name.

If anyone has better option, please tell me.

Comment: Why do you need to know? Are you installing a game and want to verify some performance requirements?

Comment: The installer should only run if there is a VGA add-on. But, there is a possibility that several desktops might have multiple VGAs add-on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write your own custom plugin or modify the HwInfo plugin.

If you are installing a game you might want to take a look at [DirectDrawEnumerateEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg426120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and similar functions or perhaps [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for devices at the GDI level.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Anders answer: I thought the same - it is not so difficult to adapt the HwInfo plugin. What do you need to do?

1. The [sourcecode](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/images/f/f6/HwInfo.zip) is available at the HwInfo page
2. From the sourcecode you see that the method `GetVideoCardName()` (in `NSISFunctions.cpp`) calls the `GetVideoAdapterDescription()` method in `HardwareInfo.cpp`.
3. Now you need to iterate the graphic cards and return an array. For some inspiration on how to do that check [this](http://www.etc.cmu.edu/projects/panda3d/PandaDox/Panda/html/wdxGraphicsPipe8_8cxx-source.html).
4. Compile and create a new DLL version
5. Create a new version and add a readme (with a description, credits etc.)
6. [Register](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=HwInfo%20plug-in&type=signup) or [login](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=HwInfo%20plug-in) to nsis, and upload the new version and update the page itself

It is worth to contribute (i contributed to nsis in the past) since everybody benefits.